# If I have specific "android:layout_height" with certain height on a style, will child layout need to specific

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have following questions relate to style and its children who will inherit its style.

Parent:

40dip
    0dp
    0.5

Children:

```
            ***<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>***
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21dip</item>
```

In the children style, if I include ,wrap_content

it will override the parent 40 to  name="android:layout_height">wrap_content

So, in this case , in the children style do i need to include fill_parents or something else.

So far, i have removed it without specify any layout_height...it works fine.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on my implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe is just me, but can you put a question mark somewhere in your "question"?

Comment: In the children style, if I include ,wrap_content

will override the parent 40 to name="android:layout_height">wrap_content?

So, in this case , in the children style do i need to include fill_parents or something else?

So far, i have removed it without specify any layout_height...it works fine.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I guess as you have given max height to parent .. and wrap content in the child ... so if there's any content larger than 40 dp than its gonna wrap and will come to next line automaitically will be pushing other content a bit downward.

Comment: another solution...you need to use a android: minHeight properties. this will fix my problem.